# calculated column based on the date dolumn

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a date column and I want to assign a new calculated column based on that column. I have a measure to assign the min date of the slicer (**'Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]**) which has a relation 1-many with the **'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi]** Both data type are date.

```
   stok_till_date = calculate(min ('Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]),  VALUES('Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]))
```

My formula is

```
Dönem Başı Stok =
IF (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi] ) < 'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[stok_till_date],
( 'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[Stok Giriş] ),
0
)
```

which is not calculating correctly.

This is the wrong result when the min date is 01.July.2022

Expected Result :

First column - the sum of the stock before the min slicer date,
Second Column - the transaction between the slicer min and max dates -
Third Column - Stock at the max date of the slicer (I hope this is more clear)

[image: till date]

[image: Result]

What am i doing wrong ?

Any ideas ?

Edit : when I add the stok_till_date formula as a column in the table it gives 01.01.2022 not as calculated as in the visual (01.07.2022)

[image: The formula of the minimum date of the slicer returns 01.01.2022]

Comment: Which Value is correct for the visual?

Comment: @Mik hi there. The expected result shall be  0, 0, 300 (the date of the second row is higher than the minimum date of the slicer) I couldnt get the minimum date of the slicer into the calculated column.

Comment: the minimum date of the table is 01.01.2022 however the slicer's minimum date is 01.07.2022.

Comment: Do you have other slicers that can infuence  'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi] ?

Comment: `CALCULATE( min('Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi] ),ALL( 'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'))` will return the minimum you have in Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi]

Comment: `calculate(min ('Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]),ALL('Tarihler (Stok)'))` you'll get min for 'Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]

Comment: If you can give the sample data tables and exactly which values should be shown in the visual with the sample data It will help a lot.

Comment: I have the company slicer also on the visual.

Comment: when I use the formula 'CALCULATE( min('Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi] ),ALLSELECTED( 'Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[İşlem Tarihi]))' on the slicer, it gives 02.07.2022 but on the calculated table it gives again 01.01.2022

Comment: sample file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7Pv2t57nLO93KsmeGDm2oM1SaqHl5MC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Expected Result : First column - the sum of the stock before the min slicer date, Second Column - the transaction between the slicer dates - Third Column - Stock at the max date of the slicer (I hope this is more clear)

Comment: ALLSELECTED in not ALL try ALL. When you use ALLSELECTED data can be crossfilterd by other table, for instance. I'll look throw your sample.

Comment: @Mik when I write ALL , it removes all filters then how can I get the **min date of the slicer** ?

Comment: when I tried ALL, it gives the date 01.01.2022 (which is present in the main database for other products)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246189/discussion-between-mik-and-umut-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stock Before =
        VAR minDate = MIN('Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih] )
RETURN
        CALCULATE(
                 SUM('Stok Giriş-Çıkış'[Stok Kalan])
                 ,ALL('Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih])
                 ,'Tarihler (Stok)'[Tarih]<minDate
        )
```

Comment: was that simple =) thanks again!

Comment: It's just a step by step solution ). And thank you for your kind words )